# Run VBA Excel macro once a day

Tags: excel, vba, schedule

I have some Excel macro which works on a specific Excel worksheet. It checks some table and sends reminder email to some people as needed.
I want that this macro will run once a day in order to check the table every day so I will not need to open the worksheet and to do it myself every day.Does it availabe to do it? I heard about Windows task scheduler as one option, Do you think that is a good option for my purpose?

Comment: Either Windows task scheduler or any other scheduler is the only option you have. The excel file is just a document. Unless otherwise, you trigger a macro from outside to send a mail, it is not possible to get a macro that is inside the excel to be executed on daily basis automatically. Sending a mail only once in a day can be incorporated in inside the macro. however triggering that macro on daily basis has to be done only by the external utility.

Comment: If you were willing to leave the Excel file permanently open you could add an `OnTime` event to your macro, but that is usually not practical, so Task Scheduler is probably the best way to go.

Comment: @Karpak What about running a VbScript (or batch file) which runs that macro?

Comment: @Masoud. Either through VB Script or through any other script or through any other type of executable (bat, com, exe or shell). Ultimately it has to be triggered by an external task scheduler.

Comment: @Karpak What I meant was making that vbs running with task scheduler instead of opening the xl file and make the macro running upon that. I agree that it has to be done through the task scheduler.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. But Whether you open the excel in foreground or background, the excel file has to be opened at any cause to check the table where the data is available..

Comment: [Why accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Accepting an answer helps other people with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduler is a good option as you say.  To spawn a new process and open a workbook you'd have a command line specifiying (1) The Excel executable and (2) the workbook to open so something like

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\Excel.exe "c:\MyWorkbook.xlsm"
```

I'd advise double quotes around the full path to the workbook (but not required for the Excel.exe).

Then in MyWorkbook.xlsm you can write code that runs upon workbook opening, classically this has been `sub Auto_Open` in any standard module or `Sub Workbook_Open()` in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a VBScript file and make that to run every day using task scheduler. I prefer this, cause then I can open the Excel file any time of the day and the macro won't run (in case you just want it to update only at that specific time).

This is the VBscript you need to write in notepad and then save with `*.vbs` extension.

```
Option Explicit
'On Error Resume Next 'Comment-out for debugging
ExcelMacro

Sub ExcelMacro() 

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    Set xlBook = 
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open("path\to\the\file.xlsm", 0, True) 

         xlApp.Run "Update" 'Name of your Sub
         xlBook.Save
         xlBook.Close
         xlApp.Quit 

    Set xlBook = Nothing 
    Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Then you can set the event scheduler from the command-line, like this from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx):

```
schtasks /Create [/S <system> [/U <username> [/P [<password>]]]]
[/RU <username> [/RP <password>]] /SC <schedule> [/MO <modifier>] [/D <day>]
[/M <months>] [/I <idletime>] /TN <taskname> /TR <taskrun> [/ST <starttime>]
[/RI <interval>] [ {/ET <endtime> | /DU <duration>} [/K] [/XML <xmlfile>] [/V1]]
[/SD <startdate>] [/ED <enddate>] [/IT] [/Z] [/F]
```

Other links you may find useful:

[Task Scheduler from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/615656/task-scheduler-from-the-command-line) from **SuperUser**

[What is a simple way to schedule a single event to happen at some time in the future?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37793/what-is-a-simple-way-to-schedule-a-single-event-to-happen-at-some-time-in-the-fu) from **Linux & Unix**

[How to Schedule Programs to Run Automatically in Windows 7?](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-schedule-programs-run-automatically-windows-7.htm) from **Gizmo's freeware (TechSupportAlert)**